# How to implement twitter summary card in javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-card

So I am on the website I know I need to include the meta tags and what not. However, there is nothing in the docs explaining what to do in the javascript. This is what I have so far

```
.data('bragData', higiBrag.createResponse('twitter', shareMessage + ' ' + profileUrl))
            .data('shareable', shareable)
            .data('shareableType', shareableType)
            .attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURI(shareMessage + ' ' + profileUrl));
```

I really have no clue on what to do. I read that you can't bind images to a web intent for twitter.